# SQL WHERE filter

Tags: sql

I suck at explaining this issue, but I hope someone understands.

How do I filter something out of a column if it meets just one criteria out of the whole value?

So in this example I want to filter out any value that includes "First Touch", even if the value has other **SpecialNeedsTagNames** as well. For example **"First Touch, Do Not Contact, Self-Serve Pilot"** etc..

```
    SELECT count(*) AS count
    FROM
      (select *
       from OperationalReporting.VW_Delivery
       WHERE DeliveryCountry in ('NO',
                         'FI',
                         'DK',
                         'SE',
                         'IS')) AS expr_qry
    WHERE "CountryOfUse" = 'Sweden'
    AND "OrderStatus" IN ('Booked',
                    'Order Placed')
  AND "IsDelivered" = 'false'
  AND "Model" NOT IN ('Model QW',
                  'Model PX',
                  'Model ZY')
  AND ((SalesAdvisorHomeStore like 'EU-SE%'
        OR CommisionabaleStore like 'EU-SE%')
       AND (SpecialNeedsTagName is null
            or (SpecialNeedsTagName not like '%First Touch%')))
    ORDER BY count DESC
    LIMIT 50000;
```

Currently it only filters out the values that ONLY have "First Touch", as soon as it has a combined value it still outputs in the column.[Faulty values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfqU3.png)

Comment: Please provide data sample and the desired result.  Based on your description you could be needing `NOT EXISTS (....)` condition.

Comment: I am not able to provide the data unfortunately. The desired result should be as in the linked picture, but with any line including "First Touch" filtered out

Comment: We do not need your *actual* data - just something that can be a good illustration.

Answer (score 0):

So first things first, you may want to unify all values in you column by giving UPPER or LOWER. The where statement would look like this:

```
WHERE UPPER(SpecialNeedsTagName) LIKE 'FIRST TOUCH%'
```

If you want to make sure that there are no nulls add `AND IS NOT NULL`.
This where will return you all of results that starts with FIRST TOUCH. If you are expecting that this phrase may occure in the middle of string add % at the beginning (`'%FIRST TOUCH%'`)

Comment: It does already run with % at both beginning and end, still shows results including "First Touch". Also the NULL should be reported as in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
SELECT count(*) AS count
    FROM
      (select *
       from XX.XX_XX
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from XX.XX_XX where UPPER(SpecialNeedsTagName) 
    LIKE '%First Touch%'))
    ORDER BY count DESC
    LIMIT 50000;
```

Comment: Updated the code to include the full one, should have probably done that from the beginning.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).